# How do i access a double nested response from firebase realtime database?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

[database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hXQ7.png)

so this is my database structure and i'm trying to access the key "amount"
i have tried accessing it like this:
[code for accessing and assigning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIg6e.png)

but i keep getting this error ==
[error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKq1K.png)

please i'm stuck

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The orderData from which you are trying to obtain the information is another Map<String, dynamic>, so you first need to access the value of that one, before you can call orderData['amount'], orderData['dateTime'], etc...

You can do this with

```
orderData = orderData.values.elementAt(0);
```

This assumes that orderData always contains at least 1 element, so it might be good to check for this and in case it is not true, throw/handle an Exception.